# Difference between List and List<Object>

Tags: java, generic-collections

Can anyone point the difference between the `List` and `List<Object>` in Java.

Also how does java differentiate the old collections and new Generic supported classes ?

How does it make it backward compatible?

Comment: In one line - never ever use `List`, and use `List<Object>` when you need a container only for `Object`s.

Comment: Sayem :Can you explain how the JVM gets to know that a particular code has old raw collections or generic supported collections.

Comment: The same way it detects a type parameter, by parsing the type declaration, I guess.